Generators of the group $GL_{n}(\mathbb{Z}_p)$.
Let $p$ be a prime and $n\ge 2$. Let
$\mathbb Z_p$ denote the finite field with $p$ elements.
I want to know about the generating sets of the group $GL_{n}(\mathbb{Z}_p)$. It is known that $GL_{2}(\mathbb{Z}_2)\cong S_3$ and a generating set is $$GL_{2}(\mathbb{Z}_2)=\left\langle{\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}}\right\rangle.$$ I want to know how the other $GL_{n}(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ groups are generated.

@DerekHolt Yes, I should have written "a generating set" instead. Just edited.

Let $\xi$ be a generator of the multiplicative group of $\Bbb F_q$. A generating set of $GL_n(\Bbb F_q)$ for $q>2$ is given by
$$
\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1\cr 
-1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
 & & \ddots &  & \cr
0 & 0 & \cdots & -1 & 0 & \end{pmatrix}, \quad
\begin{pmatrix} \xi & 0 & \cdots & 0 \cr 
0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
 & & \ddots & \cr
0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
For a reference see this paper.

What is the relation between these two generators?

The relation is a bit longer, see H.S.M. Coxeter, W.O.J. Moser, Generators and relations for discrete groups.
